# Inequality with the positive integer.

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Let $k$ be positive integers, $k=1,2,-,n!-1$ when $n \ge100$.
Show that $ \frac{l}{m} \in [\frac{k}{n!},\frac{k+1}{n!}] \Rightarrow m >n$ where 
$ \frac{l}{m}\in [0,1] $ and $l,m$ are relatively prime.
I think it is true. But, it is difficult to prove this well.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take $l=1$, $m=2$, and $k=n!/2$.

Comment: That's a special case. Is it possible to generalize that for all cases?

Comment: This case shows that $m < n$. Consequently, your assertion that $m >n$ is incorrect.

Comment: wooh.. Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

if you mean $\frac{l}{m}\in (\frac{k}{n!},\frac{k+1}{n!})$ then we can easily deduce $0<mk-ln!<m$ but if $m<n$ $m|mk-ln!$.